# Powershell Trap and Handle Error in Function

Tags: powershell, error-handling

How can I handle errors in a function without propagating it up to the main function?

```
function main() {
    trap {
        "main caught it too!"
    }
    subroutine
}
function subroutine() {
    trap {
        "subroutine caught error"
        Break
    }
    1/0
}
main
```

Results in:

```
subroutine caught error
main caught it too!
Attempted to divide by zero.
...
```

I want subroutine to handle it's own error and I don't want to change global error handling settings `$ErrorActionPreference` or rely on the user to set an `-ErrorAction` parameter.

Comment: `Break` -> `Continue`

Comment: what does break -> continue mean?

Comment: @4c74356b41 That means OP should change `Break` to `Continue`, because `Break` in `trap` actually means that error should terminate script, unless some else error handler handle it.

Comment: But it would also continue processing the function after the line where the error was thrown - this would lead to a different logic.

Comment: you could omit "break" completely in that case, but that would change the logic, just like restless said

Comment: @restless1987 But OP asking about changing logic in the first place. If you do not want to propagate error to `main`, then you have to handle the error and resume normal execution somewhere in `subroutine`.

Comment: and you are not answering that. for example i never used trap (only try\catch) and when i saw this post i was confused, why does trap propagate error?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the only options were `Break` and `Continue` whereas `Return` seems to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange the *break* statement through a *continue* statement:

```
function main() {
     trap {
         "main caught it too!"
     }
     subroutine
}

function subroutine() {
     trap {
         "subroutine caught error"
         continue
     }
     1/0; Write-host "I was executed after the ERROR"
}
main
subroutine caught error
I was executed after the ERROR
```

If that is not enough I would go with try/catch as @restless1987 sugested.

[Windows IT Pro](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/error-trapping-and-handling-powershell)  gives a nice description about *trap*.

Answer (score 0):

trap does not handle the error completely - it still passes them through. You can use `try\catch` for that:

```
function main() {
try {
    subroutine
}
catch{
    "main caught it too!"
}
}
function subroutine() {
try {
    1/0
}
catch{
    "subroutine caught error"
    Break
}
}
main
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to what I wanted: exit the subroutine without propagating the error further is `Return`:

```
function main() {
    trap {
        "main caught it too!" # Will not happen
    }
    subroutine
}
function subroutine() {
    trap {
        "subroutine caught error"
        Return
    }
    1/0
    "this will not execute"
}
main
```

Output:

```
subroutine caught error
```